# Find $A^m B^n$ for noncommutative variables

Tags: combinatorics, noncommutative-algebra

Let
$$
\begin{cases}
AC=CA+\alpha A,\\
BC=CB+\beta B,\\
AB=BA+\gamma C.
\end{cases}
$$
It is no so hard to find that
\begin{gather*}
A^n C^m=(C+\alpha n)^m A^n,\\
B^n C^m=(C+\beta n)^m B^n.
\end{gather*}

Unfortunately I cant find a good formula for $A^m B^n.$ For  $m=1$ I have got
$$
A B^n=B^n A+n \gamma B^{n-1}(C-\frac{n-1}{2} \beta).
$$

Similar, but some complicated formulas I have for $m=2,3$ but I cant see what will  be for arbitrary $m$ and $n.$

Is there any way to present $A^m B^n$  in not ugly form?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a particular reason for the asymmetry in the relations? I would expect $[A,B]=\gamma C$ to be paired with something like $[A,C]=\beta B$ rather than $[A,C]=\alpha A$...

Comment: The same kind of "assymetry" you may see in the relations for Lie algebra $sl_2.$

Comment: What's the difference between equation 1 and 2? They transform into each other when variables are relabelled according to $(A,\alpha)\leftrightarrow(B,\beta)$.

Comment: yes, they are similar but still different equations

Comment: Calculating $A^mB^n$ what operator ordering would you like in the result?  $BCA$?

Comment: @Qmechanic I prefer $BAC$

Comment: Can you set up an induction?

Comment: @user619894  yes, no problem

Comment: Not clear to me if you want $BAC$, why did you expand $B^n C^n$, since it is already normal ordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another example of [this technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4445871/617446):

Define generating functions:

\begin{array}{cc}
V(x)= & e^{xA}B\\
W(x,y)= & e^{xA}e^{yB}
\end{array}

A useful relation:

$$e^{-\tau B}Ce^{\tau B}=-\beta\tau B+C$$

proof:

Define $Z(\tau)=e^{-\tau B}Ce^{\tau B}$, then:

$$Z'=e^{-\tau B}(CB-BC)e^{\tau B}=-\beta B$$

$$Z(\tau)=-\beta\tau B+C$$

Let us normal order $V$:

$$V'=e^{xA}AB=e^{xA}(BA+\gamma C)=VA+e^{xA}\gamma C$$

integrate

$$V=V(0)e^{xA}+\gamma\int^{x}e^{\tau A}Ce^{-\tau A}d\tau e^{xA}=V(0)e^{xA}+\gamma\int_{0}^{x}\left(\beta\tau B+C\right)d\tau e^{xA}$$

setting $V_{0}=V(0)=B$

$$V=(B+\gamma xC+\frac{1}{2} \gamma \beta x^{2}B)e^{xA}$$

Now consider the double generating function $W(x,y)$

$$\partial_{y}W=e^{xA}Be^{yB}=V(x)e^{yB}=(B+\gamma xC+\frac{1}{2}\gamma \beta x^{2}B)e^{xA}e^{yB}=(B+\gamma xC+\frac{1}{2}\gamma\beta x^{2}B)W(x,y)$$

which can be directly integrated (fixing $x$)

$$W=e^{y(B+\gamma x C+\frac{1}{2}\gamma \beta x^{2}B)}W(x,0)=e^{y(B+\gamma xC+\frac{1}{2}\gamma \beta x^{2}B)}e^{xA}$$

Expanding in $x,y$ will provide any combination of $A^{n}B^{m}$needed. I hope I didn't mess up any commutation.

Comment: Thank you! There are some questions. Seems you have lost $\gamma$ after integrating $V.$ Are  $x$ and $y$  commutative?

Comment: I fixed the $\gamma$s I hope. Yes, x,y are $c$ numbers.

Comment: BTW, I can disentangle the $e^{(uB+vC)}$ exponential if needed.

Comment: I am tried to find $AB$. It must be the coefficient by $xy$ in 
$$
e^{y(B+\gamma xC+\frac{1}{2}\gamma \beta x^{2}B)}e^{xA}.
$$
I got 
$$
[xy]e^{y(B+\gamma xC+\frac{1}{2}\gamma \beta x^{2}B)}e^{xA}=\gamma BC+BA
$$
but must be $BA+\gamma C.$ 

Where is my mistake?

Comment: I get $\left(1+y(B+x\gamma C+\frac{1}{2}\beta\gamma x^{2}B)\right)(1+xA)\approx1+yB+xA+xy(BA+\gamma C)$

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you!