# Integrating by integrating under the integral sign — the other Feynman trick?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Having been introduced to the [Feynman technique of integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule), it seemed natural to wonder if it could be done the other way:

1. Introduce a new parameter $a$
2. Integrate with respect to $a$
3. Integrate with respect to the variable $x$
4. Differentiate with respect to $a$
5. Set $a=1$ and add a constant by hand

For instance,

\begin{align}
\int x \cos(x) dx =& \frac{d}{da}\int \int x \cos(ax) da dx\\
=& \frac{d}{da}\int \frac{x \sin(ax)}{x}dx\\
=& \frac{d}{da}\int \sin(ax)dx\\
=& \frac{d}{da}\frac{-\cos(ax)}{a}\\
=& \frac{x \sin(ax)}{a} + \frac{\cos(ax)}{a^2}\\
=& x \sin(x) + \cos(x) + C
\end{align}

And that is the right answer. But I couldn't think of any problems to solve with this method that I couldn't have done with integration by parts. So I wonder if this is actually an integration technique, and whether there are problems that are best solved with that method.

Answer (score 3):

It is a legitimate method. Here is an extension of it that is more convenient than integration by parts for evaluating the integral below

$$\int_{0}^{\infty }x^ne^{-x}dx= (-1)^n \frac{d^n}{da^n} 
\bigg( \int_{0}^{\infty }e^{-ax}dx\bigg)_{a=1}
=  (-1)^n \frac{d^n}{da^n} \frac1a\bigg|_{a=1}=n!$$

Answer (score 2):

In fact, I just posted an answer with this kind on trick [enter link description here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4445871/617446) where I first introduced a parameter, then differentiated, and finally reintegrated. I suppose there are more sophisticated examples around.